# INotifyPropertyChanged on Custom DataContext Base Type doesn't fire

Tags: linq-to-sql, mocking, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I have a custom base type called `MyEntityBase` for the superclass of the types in my auto-generated `DataContext` class, `MyContext`.  In attempting to create a mock data context, I decided to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MyEntityBase` so I can generically track changes.

Here's what my class looks like:

```
public abstract class MyEntityBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Based on this class, I have created a generic `Repository<T>` class for storing instances of a specific type of entity.  The basic idea behind this class is to provide methods similar to a datacontext, but instead backed by an in-memory list.  I also want to simulate tracking changes, since the change set is important to the business logic of our application for syncing with 3rd-party systems.

Here is a basic shell implementation of `Repository<T>`:

```
public class Repository<T>
    where T : MyEntityBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected List<T> _data;
    public Repository(List<T> data)
    {
        this._data = data;
        foreach (var entity in this._data)
        {
            entity.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(entity_PropertyChanged);
        }
    }

    protected void entity_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HERE");
    }
}
```

Now I create a simple repository of type `Employee`, populate some data, and attempt to modify properties of the data.  I would expect that the `PropertyChanged` event is raised since the `Employee` object has property-change notification built-in from the auto-generated `DataContext`.  However, when I run the following code, I do not see `HERE` generated in the output anywhere:

```
var data = new List<Employee> {
    new Employee { FirstName = "Bob" },
    new Employee { FirstName = "Joe" },
};

var repo = new Repository<Employee>(data);

// This should fire the PropertyChanged event
data[0].FirstName = "John";
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**: If I change the line that subscribes to the event to the following:

```
(entity as Employee).PropertyChanged += ...
```

Then it works fine.  However, `T` is already known to be `Employee` and `entity` is an instance of type `Employee`, so what's the difference?  Even if I make the `event` in `MyEntityBase` to be `virtual`, it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I copied your code here http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/HfGdC7ypCEC4TYZ-Vb7I0A (and added virtual to Entity). That seems to work.. Perhaps there's something in Employee messing it up?

Comment: Well I don't have any control over `Employee` since it is auto-generated using `SQLMetal`.  But it does look like the difference is the lack of the `override` keyword, and removing that causes it to fail again on your test code.

Comment: So it looks like I need a way to force the inherited classes like `Employee` to always override `PropertyChanged` even though the keyword `override` isn't present.  Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workable solution implemented, so I will answer my own question.  Since I already have a command-line tool `FindAndReplaceText.exe` that I use to do some customizations to the auto-generated `MyDataContext.dbml` file, I just added another call at the end where I modify all events in the generated `MyDataContext` class to include `override`.  Coupled with making my base class use `virtual` in the definitions of the events, this solves the problem:

```
FindAndReplaceText.exe -c ^
    MyDataContext.cs ^
    "public event" ^
    "public override event"
```

Now the property changes notify properly in my test code.